# Intersect then update in R

Tags: r, updates, intersect

if I have a table like

table 1

```
id   name
1     A
2     D
3     B
4     C
```

table 2

```
id   name
2    A
3    A
4    D
5    D
```

table 3

```
id   name
1    D
3    B
4    B
5    D
```

if m1 <- table 1 and m2 <- table2 and m3 <- table3, what I did is:

```
aPid <-Reduce(intersect, list(m1$id,m2$id,m3$id))
```

and I want to update tables based on intersected id such as:

```
m11 <- applyIndexToDataFrame(m1, m1$id %in% aPid)
m22 <- applyIndexToDataFrame(m2, m2$id %in% aPid)
m33 <- applyIndexToDataFrame(m3, m3$id %in% aPid)

'applyIndexToDataFram' is not real function. I just made up
```

Then finally:

table 1

```
id   name
3     B
4     C
```

table 2

```
id   name
3     A
4     D
```

table 3

```
id   name
3     B
4     B
```

Is there any function to update tables based on intersected data in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "applyIndextoDataFrame" function can be achieved just by using bracket sub-setting notation:

```
m11 <- m1[m1$id %in% aPid,]
```

You can do it in one call if you like as:

```
m11 <- m1[m1$id %in% Reduce(intersect, list(m1$id,m2$id,m3$id)),]
```